# Resize Dialog Box in KivyMD

Tags: python, kivy, dialog, kivymd

I am trying to have a dialog box to contain a MDTextField and a keyboard. I want the dialogue to contain all the data. But, it is showing me that I applied some size to the dialog box by showing a black shadow behind the background. But when I click a key, I can see that the right format pops up quickly and then leaves the screen. Here are pictures of how it looks and how I want it to look.
[image]

Here is the code I am using.

```
    def open_keyboard(self):
        if self.dialog:
            self.dialog.dismiss()

        keyboard_content = MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical", adaptive_height = True)
        keyboard_content.add_widget(KeyboardContent())

        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            type="custom",
            content_cls=keyboard_content,
            size_hint=(0.8, .9) 
        )
        self.dialog.open()
```

And here is the kivy code

```
<KeyboardContent>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDTextField:
        id: text_input
        hint_text: "Type here"
        required: True
        max_text_length: 50

    GridLayout:
        cols: 6
        spacing: "10dp"

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "A"
            on_release:
                root.add_text("A")
                app.speak_text("a")

        MDRectangleFlatButton:
            text: "B"
            on_release:
                root.add_text("B")
                app.speak_text(self.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are trying to do, I think you just need to use the built-in `minimum_height` in a few places of your `kv` code. Since you didn't include your `KeyboardContent` class, I created one:

```
class KeyboardContent(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for letter in ascii_uppercase:
            butt = MDRectangleFlatButton(text=letter, on_release=partial(self.add_text, letter))
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(butt)

    def add_text(self, letter, button_instance):
        self.ids.text_input.text += letter
```

Then I modified your `kv`:

```
<KeyboardContent>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height

    MDTextField:
        id: text_input
        hint_text: "Type here"
        required: True
        max_text_length: 50

    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        cols: 6
        spacing: "10dp"
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

I added an `id` of `grid` to the `GridLayout` and used `self.minimum_height` in two places. Now your `open_keyboard()` method can be a bit simpler:

```
def open_keyboard(self, *args):
    if self.dialog:
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    self.dialog = MDDialog(
        type="custom",
        content_cls=KeyboardContent(),
        size_hint=(0.8, None)
    )
    self.dialog.open()
```

Note the `size_hint_y` is now `None`. This allows the height to be changed.